# Show and hide component based on current object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have a parent component `Editor` with an array of objects mapping to another component `Scene` using map method:

```js
function Editor() {
  const [URL, setURL] = useState();
  const [scenes, setScenes] = useState([]); 
const addScene = () => {
    const scene = {
      Id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
      JsonObj: canvas.getJsonObj(),
    };
    const cpScenes = [...scenes];
    cpScenes.push(scene);
    setScenes(cpScenes);
  };
  const removeScene = (scene) => {
    const cpScenes = scenes.filter((sc) => sc !== scene);
    setScenes(cpScenes);
  };
<div>
          {scenes.map((scene) => (
            <Scene
              key={Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}
              addText="scene #{f}id"
              onDelete={removeScene}
              value={scene}
              selected={true}
              length={scenes.length}
              switchScene={switchScene}
              saveCurrentScene={saveCurrent}
            />
          ))}
          <button onClick={addScene} className="btn btn-primary m-2">
            Add scene
          </button>
        </div>
```

Scene component :

```js
function Scene(props) {
  const id = useState(_uniqueId("sceneCmpn-"));
  const { value, length, switchScene, onDelete, saveCurrentScene } = props;

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div key={id}>
      <button
        id={id}
        onClick={() => {
          setSelected(true);
          switchScene(value);
        }}
      >
        Scene
      </button>
      {length > 1 && (
        <button onClick={() => onDelete(value)} className="btn btn-danger m-2">
          remove scene
        </button>
      )}
      {selected && (
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            saveCurrentScene(value);
          }}
          className="btn btn-success m-2"
        >
          Save
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to make `save button` appear when i click on `scene button`, it does work, but when i click on another scene the button stays there.

[image]

How can i make the `green save button` disappear if i switch ("click") the scene.

EDIT :
this is code of switch scene, i think is not important for this problem :

````
const switchScene = (scene) => {
    let cpScenes = [...scenes];
    const index = scenes.indexOf(scene);
    const cpJsonObj = cpScenes[index].JsonObj;
    //console.log("this object in switchScene", cpJsonObj);
    canvas.resetEditor();
    canvas.loadJson(cpJsonObj);
    canvas.exportImg();
  };
```
````

Comment: @AR.Arif that causes an infinite loop, error message: Too many re-renders

Comment: So you are asking if you want to click those other Scene buttons you want that Save button to disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Editor` component, you should add another state to check a selected scene.

```
const [selectedScene, setSelectedScene] = useState();
```

And `switchScene` function might be

```
const switchScene = (scene) => {
    let cpScenes = [...scenes];
    const index = scenes.indexOf(scene);
    const cpJsonObj = cpScenes[index].JsonObj;
    //console.log("this object in switchScene", cpJsonObj);
    canvas.resetEditor();
    canvas.loadJson(cpJsonObj);
    canvas.exportImg();
    setSelectedScene(scene); //set state change here
};
```

After that, you can modify `selected` props of `Scene` from `Editor`

```
{scenes.map((scene) => (
            <Scene
              key={Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}
              addText="scene #{f}id"
              onDelete={removeScene}
              value={scene}
              selected={selectedScene === scene}
              length={scenes.length}
              switchScene={switchScene}
              saveCurrentScene={saveCurrent}
            />
          ))}
```

From all the above changes, you need to align them with `Scene` component

Now `selected` is from props, not from state anymore

```
function Scene(props) {
  const id = useState(_uniqueId("sceneCmpn-"));
  const { value, length, switchScene, onDelete, selected, saveCurrentScene } = props;

  return (
    <div key={id}>
      <button
        id={id}
        onClick={() => {
          switchScene(value);
        }}
      >
        Scene
      </button>
      {length > 1 && (
        <button onClick={() => onDelete(value)} className="btn btn-danger m-2">
          remove scene
        </button>
      )}
      {selected && (
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            saveCurrentScene(value);
          }}
          className="btn btn-success m-2"
        >
          Save
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, the switchScene only gets the JsonObj in a scene and using another component create from it a scene with animations.. I have edited my question and added it's code

Comment: @Marwane I'm reusing `switchScene` for state changes (of course, it won't affect your main logic there), you can check it out again. If you don't understand any part of it, please let me know :D